# WiFi tether without losing battery

Tags: bluetooth, charging, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, battery-life

So, as everyone already knows, when tethering data over WiFi your battery may overheat/lose battery/etc. What I want to do is while in my car:

1. Stream internet over WiFi to >1 person
2. Navigate with GPS (a.k.a. screen on the whole time)
3. Bluetooth music to my car for Pandora or something

As you can see this will take my phone(Galaxy Nexus) to the max, but I think it should be able to do it. I'm open to other ideas, but what do people think about powering the phone with a battery bypass and charging the battery with a different circuit?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard enough to keep it charged with the GPS and streaming - I know I do it frequently. I would not recommend trying to share data at the same time. It wasn't until the latest update that I could even get streaming and WiFi hotspot to work without stuttering.

I would strongly suggest that you use another cell phone do the WiFi hotspot while your phone does the streaming and GPS or get a dedicated GPS and use the phone for hotspot and streaming.

It is a classic example of GPS, BT & Wifi Hotspot, Pick any two.

But, in the interest of science, I think you should try it ;) just have a backup plan.

Edit: Be sure to get a high amperage car charger - one for an iPad should work nicely since those require 2.1 amps. That should push a lot of juice to the phone and maybe keep it from dying under all that load.

Comment: Oh I'm trying it one way or another :) And I don't have any issues with multitasking until I tether... So I hope there is a way to cut the battery out of the loop.